# Default Date incrementation

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I want to create table with `time` column like that:

```
time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP
```

But I need to add next week date as default value. I was trying to do this:

```
time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT DATE(CURRENT TIMESTAMP)+7
```

But it's not working. What should I do?

Comment: can't do that with mysql timestamps. you'll need a trigger to do the +7 days business.

Comment: The default has to be a literal, or the specific exception `current_timestamp`, you can't use an expression. Use a trigger.